# Mocking a function of real object with Spock

Tags: grails, groovy, mocking, spock

I want to add some Controller Unit tests for a web application that is written with the Grails framework.
I need to skip `getMessage()` method that used in `cancel_request()` method in the controller as a real object.

```
class PublicControllerSpec extends Specification implements ControllerUnitTest<PublicController> {

 def "Cancel Request for user"() {
    given:
    controller.getMessage() << Spy(PublicController){
        getMessage(_ as User, _ as String) >> "SuccessMessage"
    }

    when:
    controller.cancel_request()

    then:
    response.redirectedUrl.contains('/public/list')
  }
}
```

Comment: What error are you seeing?

Comment: @tim_yates getMessage() is not mocked and give result as real object

Comment: The syntax `controller.getMessage() << Spy(PublicController) { ... }` looks awfully wrong. And please show the controller code, too. I do not use Grails, but from what I have seen in the testing documentation, it is not going to work like this. `ControllerUnitTest` is a trait used to provide a controller instance, so there is no obvious way to replace that instance with a mock object because the trait's objective is to unit-test the controller, i.e. you can mock/stub its dependencies, not the subject under test itself.

Comment: What you are doing is not unit testing but rather integration testing. Thus, you should create your controller (mock) instance by yourself and not use the `ControllerUnitTest` trait in this case. I think you are misunderstanding something here. P.S.: Classes do not have "functions", they have methods. ;-)

Comment: @kriegaex I learn from your useful lesson. Thanks a lot !!

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I don't have any experience with Grails framework, but used to work with Spock

Based on your question:

You say: controller is a real object so it should be created with a code like this in test:

```
controller = new SomeController(<dependencies>)
```

But then you specify an expectation on a real object - IMO it doesn't work like this, you can specify the expectations only on proxies (Stubs, Mocks, Spies) they have that functionality in their implementation, real objects obviously don't.

So basically you have two ways:

**Option 1: Spy the Controller**

The Controller itself must be a Spy: this is something that wraps the real object (the real controller)  and by default delegates all the method calls to that internal real object unless you don't "suppress" this functionality (in this case, you say something like: behave like a real object but if someone calls `getMessage` then return a message instead of delegating to the real object). The obvious disavantage of this way is that the object under test (controller) becomes a Spy which is not really a good approach.

**Option 2: Refactoring the code**

I admit, since I don't have an experience with Grails I might be missing something here, but if the controller is the code that you've written, you might opt for the following change:

Introduce a dependency: a class that is responsible for message calculation, for example:

```
 interface MessageCalculator {
     String getMessage()
 }

 class MyController {
      MessageCalculator messageCalculator 
      MyController(MessageCalculator messageCalculator) {
         this.messageCalculator = messageCalculator
      }


      public getMessage() {
           messageCalculator.getMessage()
      }
 }
```

Sidenote: *Yes I know there are AST tranformations that can be applicable here, but its not a subject of the question so I'll leave the code like this*

Anyway now you can re-implement the test as follows:

```
   def "test me now"() {
      given:
         def msgCalc = Stub(MessageCalculator)
         msgCalc.getMessage() >> "Successfull message"

         def controller = new MyController(msgCalc)
      ...  
   }
```

Comment: The controller is a reserved variable in the test and no need to write any code for initializing it.

Comment: Yes, but its not shown in the question and I've assumed that you create it somewhere, if not in test then maybe in some infrastructure level code of your project, someone has to create it and spock by itself can't do it, so there must be some extension. If so - you can provide/use existing a hook and inject dependency into controller if you go with option 2, otherwise you can go with option 1.

Comment: It's not shown because it is internally initialized with the framework.

Comment: So I understand that providing a hook to the framework is not an option? If so, the first way is the only one you can proceed with...